# No .debug_str found in ELF file?

Tags: c++, gcc, elf

Im doing a project that works with ELF files. Right now Im using the following as a sample input -

```
class C {
public:
    C();
    C(int x, int y);
    int getX();
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

class SubC : public C {
    int z;
};

int f() {return 0;}

C c;
SubC subC;

int i;
double d;
```

I then run

```
gcc test.cpp -g -c -o test.o
```

and I get test.o as expected. I then feed test.o into a library I found called [peter-dwarf](https://code.google.com/p/peter-dwarf/). My problem is that the library says "no section .debug_str found in test.o"

Am I doing something wrong during compilation? Or is the library not working?

Edit: should have been a -g in there

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" - no. "is the library not working" - perhaps. To understand what is going on here, please add output from `readelf -S test.o`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did that and there is a .debug_str header, so it does seem to be a problem with the library I guess. I got in contact with the guy who made it, so we will see whats up.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-g` in gcc to generate the debug symbols. You may also refer to the documentation of debugging options of gcc [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options).

The `-g` alone might not include DWARF information if your system is configured in some way. There is a number of switches related to DWARF specifically, so if `-g` alone does not work, you may need to go there and mangle with other switches.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that in my question. I did put that in, and Im STILL getting no .debug_str.

Comment: I don't have the software under my hand, but there things like `-gdwarf-version` version [2-4], `-gstrict-dwarf`, `-gsplit-dwarf` and maybe some more. Try these out too. Should not be too risky.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to compile with debugging information enabled. Try:

```
gcc -g test.cpp -c -o test.o
```